# Access string_array from activity and send selected item to another activity in android

Tags: android, arrays, button

hello friends today my question is about string_array.On my activity i created two buttons.Now on (strings.xml) i created string array name with two items and i have inserted some text as shown below.On each button click i would like to access each item individually.for example on button1 click show me first item and on button 2 click give me the 2nd item on.Can you please give me the code for button click as i have little idea on how to access item.I have created a textview activity to display my item with every click.my code is working fine till now but i need help with extra code that i have to add.Please help me .

```
// Button activity page
android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/OKILA"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
//strings.xml
    <string-array name="chapters">
        <item>this is tes1</item>
        <item>this is test2</item>
    </string-array>
```

```
//main
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class Lipok extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Toolbar mActionBarToolbar;
    Button btnOne;
    Button btnTwo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lipok);
        mActionBarToolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.CHAPTERS);
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("CHAPTERS");
    String[] chapters=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapters);

        btnOne = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btnTwo = findViewById(R.id.button1);        

        btnOne.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text="";
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn1 : {
                text = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapters)[0];
                break;
            }
            case R.id.button1 : {
                text = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapters)[1];
                break;
            }
        }


        Intent intent = new Intent(Lipok.this,lipokchapters.class);
        intent.putExtra("DATA", text);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

```
//textview activity page
package com.Aolai.temeshilai;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class lipokchapters extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lipokchapters);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.textv);
        String text= getIntent().getStringExtra("Data");
        textView.setText(text);

    }
}
```

Comment: So the textview that you want to display in is in different activity?

Comment: yes diff activity.I tried your code below but there is a problem here"Text.setText(text);" setText cannot resolve method.

Comment: What about the other activity?

Comment: i have updated please check.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: same it doesnt do anything on button click.

Comment: On sending activity you're writing "DATA" and in other activity you're writing "Data"

Comment: but still no change.I changed it back.Btw i think i havent implemented code to go to another activity page.

Comment: I have edited your code, now try this

Comment: Added findViewById for your buttons and also added listeners for them

Comment: @KaranMehta it worked.Thankyou so much for your patience and for all the troubles .upvote.

Comment: Please upvote my answer as well because it may help others as well

Comment: Reputation below 15 upvote is only recorded.Sorry but i will make sure once i reach 15  I will get back and upvote again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

xml file

```
android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/OKILA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/OKILA"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
    <string-array name="chapters">
        <item>this is tes1</item>
        <item>this is test2</item>
    </string-array>
```

Main Class

```
public class Lipok extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Toolbar mActionBarToolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lipok);
        mActionBarToolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.CHAPTERS);
        setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("CHAPTERS");

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         String text="";
         switch(v.getId()){
              case R.id.OKILA : {
                   text = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray)[0];
                   break;
              }
              case R.id.button1 : {
                   text = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray)[1];
                   break;
              }
         }
         Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             Intent intent = new Intent(this, YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.class);
             intent.putExtra("DATA", text);
             startActivity(intent);

         // Or else you can do whatever you want to do here with that text
    }
}
```

Then in your other activity

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("DATA");
YOUR_TEXTVIEW_NAME.setText(data);
```

Comment: my textview is on another activity so I need to link to that activity too

Comment: You can't link it like that, you will have to send data to that screen with intent and then setText there @newbie77

Comment: sorry to bother you but how to i send data to that screen with intent.Cause your above code isnt working.I think i have to write somecode on my other textview activity as well

Comment: "your_textview_name.setText(text)" here when i replace it with the name of my textview it doesnt accept.Maybe since its on another activity.I havent wrote any code on my textview activity.

Comment: For sending data to other screen, follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Comment: can yu just give a code like before.You did better.

Comment: What happened? @newbie77

Comment: @ Karan Metha it doesnt show anything on button click.I did the same procedure.Can you please try it yourself.

Comment: It will not show anything, It will move to next screen

Comment: @ Karan Metha  on btn click its supposed to open a textview activity page and show "this is test1".and on 2nd btn click "this is test2"

Comment: and why am i not getting that on button click?

Comment: Does it move to new screen or not?

Comment: nope my fren.I tried other ways too but it doesnt work at all.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong because you must be making some mistake or other, please upload your error image or the updated code so that i can suggest you

Comment: I edited.Please check.I have omitted toast but keeping it too give no result.The problem must be somewhere.when I run am not getting any errors.Except when i press button it doesnt move to new screen

Answer (score 0):

> This is basics of Android so before answering I suggest you to go
>   through basic tutorials before posting on Stackoberflow.

Now,

Here is how you can access the items from your `string_array`.

```
String[] chapters= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapters);
```

Now,here is pseudo code that might help you.

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(

your_text_view.setText(chapters[0])

)
//Here 0 means your first item, likewise you can access items by their index in 
 array
```